# Why does visual studio 2013 produces build errors with no error list after adding an RDLC file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, rdlc

I have a WPF project which uses Mahapps Metro UI in Visual Studio 2013. 
I added an rdlc file to be used as my report but when I tried to build the project, Visual Studio says it has build errors and the error list shows nothing. 
When I delete the rdlc file, my project builds successfully.
I tried to set the build output's verbosity to detailed and it shows the following:

```
1>Target "PrepareRdlFiles" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets" from project "C:\Users\eloj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SIMApplication\MahApps.Metro.Application1\SIMApplication.csproj" (target "CompileRdlFiles" depends on it):

1>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(Extension)'=='.rdlc') was evaluated as ('.resources'=='.rdlc').

    1>Task "CreateItem"

    1>Done executing task "CreateItem".

    1>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(Extension)'=='.rdlc') was evaluated as ('.resx'=='.rdlc').

    1>Done building target "PrepareRdlFiles" in project "SIMApplication.csproj".

    1>Target "RunRdlCompiler" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets" from project "C:\Users\eloj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SIMApplication\MahApps.Metro.Application1\SIMApplication.csproj" (target "CompileRdlFiles" depends on it):

1>Building target "RunRdlCompiler" completely.

1>Output file "obj\Debug\RdlCompile.compiled" does not exist.

1>Using "RdlCompile" task from assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91".

1>Task "RdlCompile"
1>Done executing task "RdlCompile" -- FAILED.

1>Done building target "RunRdlCompiler" in project "SIMApplication.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:12.98
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work by editing the Version and PublicKeyToken from the Microsoft Reporting Targets.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem doing this:

1. Excluding rdlc files
2. Building the project
3. Including the files
4. Build again.

Visit https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/80148/why-did-my-build-fail-in-my-winform-project-with-d